# Using multer to recieve a FormData object as a node.js server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I have an HTML form with two buttons (along with other text input areas), and I have some front end javascript code to handle the submit. On the submit, I create a FormData object and store the file in it. Then I send that through an jquery ajax request to a node.js server. However, this is where the problem is - when I try to access the file in the server, the file is always undefined - i've tried accessing it with `req.body, req.files, req.file` but its always undefined. Is this a problem with the ajax request, or the way i'm receiving it?

upload file button:

```
<input id="element_3" name="element_3" class="element file required" accept="application/pdf" type="file"/>
```

submit button:

```
<input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

handle submit:

```
$('#form_1039889').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var file = $('#element_3').get(0).files[0];
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('pdf', file);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/addPdf',
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
           //success TODO code
        }
    });
});
```

relevant server code:

```
app.post('/addPdf', [multer({dest: "./uploads/"}).single('avatar'), function(req, res) {
    console.log("file: " + req.file);
}]);
```

Comment: Does your form have an enctype of multipart/form-data ?

Comment: yes, but i'm only trying to extract the last bit (the file)

Comment: @jeshaitan The `"avatar"` in `single('avatar')` refers to the name of the input file, which you don't have.  You need therefore to set the `name` property of your input file to `'avatar'`, or any other name, providing that that name matches the parameter of the `single`` function.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of single('avatar') use single('pdf.file') because you set pdf object for file.

Answer (score 0):

Name that we pass inside Single should match with form-data key. So Change .single('avatar') with .single('pdf').
So your node js code will look like this:

```
app.post('/addPdf', [multer({dest: "./uploads/"}).single('pdf'), function(req, res) {
    console.log("file: " + req.file);
}]);
```